# Warning: "file path" \node_modules\ngx-translate-multi-http-loader\dist\multi-http-loader.js depends on 'deepmerge'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It's a micro-frontend angular project using mfe(module federation).
recently I upgraded my project from angular 13 to 14 and causes some warning like:

> node_modules\ngx-translate-multi-http-loader\dist\multi-http-loader.js depends on
> 'deepmerge'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

I tried thefollowing in `angular.json` file:

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the wrong library in your `angular.json` file.

Anyway, I fixed the issue without using `allowedCommonJsDependencies` (which is basically ignoring the warning), just by moving on to version `9.3.1` of the package `ngx-translate-multi-http-loader`. In this version the code get's published in the requested format.

Be sure to also checkout the [breaking changes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader/v/9.3.1?activeTab=readme).